# Chrome Dev tools - Network Tab is Blank

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am not able to view the Network activity in Chrome Dev tools . When I open it , it displays blank screen. Other tabs in the dev tools work just fine. Please see the image below. How can I make it work ?

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab]

[image: Chrome Version]

Comment: I'm having the same issue (same version, Linux). I guess the beta broke something

Comment: Seems that way. I am using canary build now.